# ResourceNotFound: convex_decomposition when installing Guided Policy Search library

Tags: python

I am attempting to install the [guided policy search ros package](http://rll.berkeley.edu/gps/) for the pr2, but I keep running into [this error](https://gist.github.com/ethan92429/818be2e65b737029ae12) when I attempt to build. I think it is because I am missing some python dependencies, but it doesn't appear to list which dependencies and the source code looks like it is supposed to install them automatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just install manually

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-convex-decomposition
```